# Filter out thin shapes produced by skimage.measure

Tags: python

I'm trying to detect large blob objects.

I've used skimage.measure to sort out connected components with a connectivity of 1 with counts greater than 9.

from skimage import measure

```
from skimage import measure

all_labels = measure.label(np.isnan(arr), connectivity=1)

unique, counts = np.unique(all_labels, return_counts=True)
filtered_labels = measure.label(np.isin(all_labels,list(np.argwhere(counts>9))[1:])*all_labels)
```

My labels show up like this:

[image]

Some of them are lines, and some of them are blobs. Is there a good way to check the true thickness of the shape? I would go by max height and max width around the box of shape, but some of the lines go diagonally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cv functions that return rotated bounding boxes and ellipses: you are basically interested to see if the minimum bounding box around your blobs has an area < threshold. You can get that (possibly rotated) bounding box or ellipse with `cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)`
after you got your contours, or `cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)` for the ellipse.

Another viable approach is to use [erosion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/erosion-dilation-images-using-opencv-python/) to check which "thin" shapes have been totally eroded/deleted.